# combine reader monad with choice

Tags: functional-programming, f#, pattern-matching

I have this two types

```
open FSharpx
open FSharpx.Reader

type First =
    { Name: string
      Items: string list }

type Second =
    { Name: string
      Numbers: int list }
```

Using a Reader monad from the [FSharpx](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Extras/) library I can do this

```
let map f =
        fun n xs ->
            { Name = n; Items = xs } // : Second
    <!> Reader.ask (fun (o:First) -> o.Name)
    <*> (List.map f <!> Reader.asks (fun o -> o.Items))
```

and I execute this without problem

```
> let first = {Name="stuff";Items=["1";"2";"3"]}
> map int first;;
val it : Second = {Name = "stuff";
                   Numbers = [1; 2; 3];}
```

the problem is that the function `int` is not safe, so I have to `protect` it into a `Choice` type.

```
> let safeInt = Choice.protect int
val safeInt : (int -> Choice<int,exn>)
```

Now, how do I use this function in my `map` function from `First` to `Second`?

my attempt is using pattern matching by creating a wrapper function with the knowledge of the `Choice` type

```
let second n = function
    | Choice1Of2 xs -> Choice1Of2 {Name=n;Numbers=xs}
    | Choice2Of2 err -> Choice2Of2 err

let map' f =
    mapping
    <!> Reader.ask (fun (o:First) -> o.Name)
    <*> (Choice.mapM f <!> Reader.ask (fun o -> o.Items))
```

but this is not good because it might seem from outside the module that `Second` might not have an Number property

Is there a better way to apply the result of a choice type to my example?

Comment: if you just want to convert `First` to `Second`: https://gist.github.com/mausch/4bc056cb78a195e95d2eefb42f3a9f91